# Why the message is "name is not defined" rather than "variable referenced before assignment" in global scope?

Tags: python

[One unreachable assignment statement made one "defined but not assigned" name in local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968983/why-commented-assignment-statement-in-the-if-false-block-cause-difference-na) but this is not for global scope:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#global scope
if False:
 baz = 4
 pass
#Raise "NameError: name 'baz' is not defined"
print(baz)
```

I expect get the message similar to `variable 'baz' referenced before assignment` in global scope as in local scope but actual message is `name 'baz' is not defined` in global scope.

I running in Python 3.7.2+.

Comment: Presumably because you're not trying to mutate `baz`, simply reference it. I actually don't know the exact distinction between the two errors

Comment: `baz` is never assigned a value, hence it raises that *"name 'baz' is not defined"*. On the other hand, *"..referenced before assignment"* usually occurs when you try to modify a variable inside a function though you defined it outside (not inside function) but not in global scope.

Answer (score 2):

In a function scope, Python analyzes all assignment operations to produce a complete list of the variables that scope should have. A local variable lookup is known at bytecode compilation time to correspond to at least one actual assignment to that variable in the function body, so the exception message for an unbound local variable mentions assignments.

No such analysis happens at global or class scope, and no such analysis could possibly be comprehensive, due to operations like `from whatever import *` and `globals().update(stuff)` that bind variables unknown at compile time. Python makes no attempt to keep track of what variables the global scope "should" have, and it doesn't try to distinguish between

```
print(a)
a = 1
```

where the variable is used before binding, and

```
print(b)
```

where there is no binding operation at all, or

```
thing = 1
print(thinh)
```

where `thinh` is a typo. The same error message template is used whether or not there's an assignment, so it wouldn't make as much sense for the template to say "before assignment" when there might not be an assignment at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you see `NameError:`, Python is trying to use a variable or function based on a previous definition. If you don't define your variable you will get this error.

In your code because your variable is only defined when you have declared something `False` Python can not pass it through globally to the rest of your code. You can make **baz** `global` by defining it before your false statement. There are a number of ways to achieve it however it is dependent on what your goal is. Here is an example:

```
baz = 0

if False:
    baz = 4

print(baz)
```

Output: `0`

Then when True:

```
baz = 0

if True:
    baz = 4

print(baz)
```

Output: `4`